# React: Simulate mobile screen width inside of a modal

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, bootstrap-grid

I have a component with a desktop styling

[image]

and a mobile styling, which occurs when the browser width is less than 750px

[image]

I would like to present this component inside of a modal, which is 600px, but have the component behave as if the browser width is 600px. When the component is not presented in a modal it should behave normally, with the styling being adjusted according the width of the browser, but when the component is presented inside a modal, I would like it to behave as if the screen width is the width of the modal.

Right now, the component is taking the desktop styling inside a modal which is 600px wide, like below, but I would like the component to take the styling which is above, where those circles are stacked in a column.

[image]

---

[Here is a repository of the code I have for this problem](https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/simulate-mobile-view).
The only difference I want to make is that the circles should be stacked when they appear inside the modal, but they should be styled the same way on the '/other' page.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a property in your Content component to change your style accordingly:

```
export default ({ insideModal }) => (
  <div className="d-flex flex-md-row flex-column"
   style={{ flexDirection: `${insideModal ? "column" : "row" }` }}
  >
    <Image />
    <Image />
    <Image />
  </div>
);
```

And then include in your Modal component:

```
const Modal = () => (
  <div
    style={{ width: 500, backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)", top: "50%" }}
    className="position-fixed m-auto"
  >
    <Content insideModal />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: My problem is that I already have a few pages  styled for desktop and mobile, and I would like to just take the mobile styling and place it inside of modal, without needing to change anything